# InetAddress.getByName returning wrong IP address

Tags: java, serversocket

I have been using the following code on a server.

```
public SocketServer(int port,String inetAddress) throws IOException {
        this.port = port;
        this.ia = InetAddress.getByName(inetAddress);
        log.info(String.format("Internet Address %s using port  %d  for provided IP Address  %s", this.ia.toString() ,this.port ,inetAddress.toString()));
        s = new ServerSocket(port,50,this.ia );
    }
```

This works fine on my local server but on production it is providing wrong address. 
Production server do contain following type of IPs:-

- Private IP
- VPN IP
- Public IP

I am providing private IP and expecting the server to connect using that private IP but instead it is connecting using the VPN IP.

One more thing i though to do was to use InetAddress.getByAddress() but i am unable to convert my IP in string to a byte array. 
Can anyone suggest me any solution in this regard?

Comment: do getByAddress to see if it is beter i.e. `this.ia = InetAddress.getByAddress(inetAddress)`

Comment: Yes I have tried to do the same as mentioned in my question above. But i am unable to convert my raw string "10.20.30.40" into a proper byte array that will be accepted by getByAddress

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken this might be a problem related to DNS. InetAddress.getByName(String host) will return the first IP address assigned to a certain domain name.

I.e. if in your /etc/hosts file you have something like this

```
192.168.1.1  sandbox1
192.168.1.2  sandbox1
```

The code

```
InetAddress.getByName("sandbox1")
```

will always give you 192.168.1.1

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes i am also thinking on the same lines and even thought about using getAllByName to get an array of InetAddress. But i am also trying to use InetAddress.getByAddress but i can't use it as it expect Array of Bytes.

Comment: Not exactly DNS but the name resolution mechanism; but yes, that's it. Note that there is the possibility to obtain all addresses from a name with the `.getAllByName()` method of `InetAddress`.

Comment: Can anyone suggest a usage of getByAddress in this case?

Comment: @hellowahab the problem here seems to be a system configuration problem; you have a same machine name resolving to different addresses, OK, that can be understood; but this same name seems to resolve to completely unrelated addresses as well, and this is a configuration problem. For instance, why would a same name resolve to both an address of a public interface and an address of a VPN interface?

Comment: @fge I am providing raw IP like "10.10.10.10" inside getByName I am not providing a host name like abc.com my expectation was that it will return the same raw IP as InetAddress but it seem like returning the VPN IP instead. I am thinking to use GetByAddress but unable to use that due to difference in parameter

Comment: Can you elaborate on the VPN / Network setup in a bit more detail? What does you hosts file look like? What are your interfaces what IP addresses do they have. Is there NAT or some similar technology involved?

Comment: @hellowahab you mean that if you try and `.getByName("10.10.10.10")` you end up with a different address? That is very strange, since the javadoc of the method explicitly mentions that "[...]If a literal IP address is supplied, only the validity of the address format is checked"